# Different Featured Images depending on context: loop or single view

Tags: post-thumbnails

I want to keep different image on the single post type page and a different image if the post type is showing in a loop. Is there any way?

Perhaps we can use the gallery image as featured on single view but if so, how?

Comment: if you just want a different image size of the same image, you can do that a bit simpler, otherwise use @cjbj's solution.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this is to use the [Multiple Post Thumbnails plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-post-thumbnails/). Once you have done this, add the following snippet to your functions file:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) {
    new MultiPostThumbnails(array(
    'label' => __('Secondary Featured Image', 'yourtextdomain')
    'id' => 'secondary-image',
    'post_type' => 'post'
    ));
    }
```

This will make a box 'Secondary Featured Image' available on your edit post page. Now you will have to place it in your theme, wherever you want the secondary featured image to appear in stead of the primary:

```
if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) 
    MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image');
else
    the_post_thumbnail(); //fallback in case somebody doesn't have the plugin installed
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks. Two things though.

1. I need it for product, not post. Will that work?
2. Where to add that second snippet you posted?

Comment: The product is presumably a custom post type. You would have to change the line that says `'post_type' => 'post'`, but I don't know to what post type, because I don't know how your custom post type is defined. The second snippet would go into the template file where you want the secondary featured image to display. For instance, if you want it on single pages, open `single.php` and replace `the_post_thumbnail` in that file with the snippet.

Comment: It is Woocommerce. So I think its name would be "product" right ? 

I added the plugin but the secondary area does not seem to show in Products

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with woocommerce, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: No problem. I hope someone pops up.

Comment: yeah, or read the manual: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/installed-taxonomies-post-types/